# Multipart POST with Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I want to make a request to my Rails server using Alamofire in Swift.
I have a simple object on that I would like to serialize as well as a few images that I would like to attach as multipart-encoded data.

On my rails side it is as simple as a request :

```
post :create, object: parameters, files: ['file1', 'file2'], format: :json
```

What's the most elegant way to do this with Alamofire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't dug to far into Alamo fire yet, but reading the documentation leads me to believe this is not supported in Alamo Fire at this time.  Specifically the end of the document under the header "When should I use AFNetworking" states:

Use AFNetworking for any of the following:

- UIKit extensions, such as asynchronously loading images to UIImageView
- TLS verification, using AFSecurityManager
- Situations requiring NSOperation or NSURLConnection, using AFURLConnectionOperation
- Network reachability monitoring, using AFNetworkReachabilityManager
- Multipart HTTP request construction, using AFHTTPRequestSerializer

Comment: Thanks Brandon, I imported AFNetworking for this call and it appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking

**In Swift 3**

But for Implementing **MultiPartFormdata**
Following Code Can be useful

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
        multipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.Imgprofile.image!, 1)!, withName: "Prescription", fileName: "Profile_Image.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
    }, to:"Your URL Here")
    { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            print(result)

            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                print(progress)
            })

            upload.responseJSON { response in
                //print response.result
                print(response);
            }

        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError);
        }
    }
}
```

This Is The Latest Working Syntax